# Create multilevel dictionary from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build out multilayer dictionary.
The input looks like this.

```
my_list = [['Japan', 'Consumer Durables'], ['United States', 'Electronic Technology', 'ANALYST PICK'], ['Japan', 'Finance'], ['South Korea', 'Electronic Technology']]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['country','sector','flag'])
```

```
    country sector  flag
0   Japan   Consumer Durables   None
1   United States   Electronic Technology   ANALYST PICK
2   Japan   Finance None
3   South Korea Electronic Technology   None
```

And desired output looks like this.

```
{"groups" :
    [
        {
            "name" : "Japan",
            "groups" :
                [
                    {"name" : "Consumer Durables", "indices" : [0]},
                    {"name" : "Finance", "indices" : [2]}
                ],
        },
        {
            "name" : "United States",
            "groups" :
                [
                    {
                        "name" : "Electronic Technology",
                        "groups" :
                            [
                                {"name" : "ANALYST PICK", "indices" : [1]}
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "South Korea",
            "groups" :
                [
                    {"name" : "Electronic Technology", "indices" : [3]}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Each indices refers the index of the original dataframe.
I tried to build the code with for loops but had no luck.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out myself.
Although the code itself is obviously not clean.

```
#Set Initial Value
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

my_list = [['Japan','Consumer Durable'], ['United States', 'Electronic Technology', 'ANALYST PICK'], ['Japan', 'Finance'], ['South Korea', 'Electronic Technology']]

print("\n*********Showing Original Data*********")
print(my_list)
print("*********Showing Original Data*********\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['country','sector','flag'])

print("\n*********Showing converted Format*********")
display(df)
print("*********Showing converted Format*********\n")

#Convert split pandas data frame to df_key : grouping name, df_val : indices
df_val = [list(i) for i in df.groupby(list(df.columns)).groups.values()]
df_key = []

for i in df.groupby(list(df.columns)).groups.keys():
    temp_list = []
    for j in i:
        if not pd.isnull(j):
            temp_list.append(j)
        else:
            pass 
    df_key.append(temp_list)

#Set temporary variables.
my_dict = {}
my_dict2 = []

for i,j in zip(df_key,df_val):

    #Iterate through key index
    for k in range(len(i)-1,-1,-1):

        #Check if this is the last key
        if k == len(i)-1:

            #For the last key, create indices dictionary
            my_dict = {i[k] : {"indices" : j}}
        else:

            #For those NOT the last key, contain it with higher level.
            my_dict = {i[k] : my_dict}

    #Append converted dictionary to list
    my_dict2.append(my_dict)

    #Dictionary initialization.
    my_dict = {}    


def get_all_keys(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        yield key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from get_all_keys(value)


def update(d, u):
    for k,v in u.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):

            # print(""*********Checking varialbes"*********"")
            # print("d is {0}".format(d))
            # print("u is {0}".format(u))
            # print("k is {0}".format(k))
            # print("v is {0}".format(v))
            # print(""*********Checking varialbes"*********"")
            
            d[k] = update(d.get(k,{}), v)
        else:

            # print"(*********Checking varialbes"*********)"
            # print("d is {0}".format(d))
            # print("u is {0}".format(u))
            # print("k is {0}".format(k))
            # print("v is {0}".format(v))
            # print("*********Checking varialbes"*********")

            d[k] = v
        return d

my_dict3 = {}
for i in my_dict2:
    my_dict3 = update(my_dict3,i)

print("\n*********Showing converted Format*********")
print(my_dict3)
print("*********Showing converted Format*********\n")


#Function to convery key to 'groups' key
def convert_dict(d):
    for k in list(d.keys()):
        #Those keys NOT 'name' and 'indices' will be rounded with 'groups' dictionary
        if (k != 'name' and k != 'indices'):
            #Construct 'groups' key
            d["groups"] = d.get("groups", [])
            #Add 'name' and original key value to 'groups' key
            d["groups"].append(update(d[k],{"name" : k}))
            #Delete original key
            d.pop(k)
        else:
            pass
    return d

#Function to execute convert_dict interatively for each keys 
def iterate_convert_dict(d):
    #Check the key value is nested dictionary, filtered out for 'name' and 'indices' key 
    temp_check = list(filter(lambda x:x!='name' and x!='indices',d.keys()))

    # print("*********Checking varialbes"*********")
    # print("d is {0}".format(d))
    # print("d.keys is {0}".format(list(d.keys())))
    # print("temp_check is {0}".format(temp_check))
    # print("*********Checking varialbes"*********")

    #If the key value is not nested dictionary, then pass.
    if temp_check == []:
        pass
    #If the key value is nested dictionary, then execute convert_dict and recursively run the function
    else:
        d = convert_dict(d)
        for i in d["groups"]:
            iterate_convert_dict(i)
    return d

print("\n*********Showing converted Format*********")
print(iterate_convert_dict(my_dict3))
print("*********Showing converted Format*********\n")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The provided output is invalid (dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys), however a close output would be:

```
out = {'groups':
 [{'name': k, 'groups': [{'name': name, 'index': idx}
                         for name, idx in g.reset_index()
                                           .groupby('sector')['index']
                                           .agg(list).to_dict().items()]}
  for k,g in df.groupby('country')]
      }
```

output:

```
{'groups': [{'name': 'Japan',
             'groups': [{'name': 'Consumer Durables', 'index': [0]},
                        {'name': 'Finance', 'index': [2]}]},
            {'name': 'South Korea',
             'groups': [{'name': 'Electronic Technology', 'index': [3]}]},
            {'name': 'United States',
             'groups': [{'name': 'Electronic Technology', 'index': [1]}]}]}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. That is why each group contained in the list. For example, 'Japan' has two sector which composed it's list. However your answer, there is no 'flag' group for 'United States', 'Electronic Technology'.

Comment: @SungminSon yet it is. Try to copy paste your dictionary in a python shell and let me know where the `{"name" : "Consumer Durables", "indices" : [0]}` disappeared ;)

Comment: Regarding the `flag` it seems ignored in the provided output but you can easily add it with the same logic

Comment: I see. I should have concat Finance and Consumer Durable in the same list. Let me play around with your answer. Thanks!

Comment: If the index only has group level 1, it doesn't work.

my_list = [['Japan'], ['United States', 'Electronic Technology', 'ANALYST PICK'], ['Japan', 'Finance'], ['South Korea', 'Electronic Technology']]

Output should have index for Japan group. I quickly go over your solution, but it seems like only checking second group level index. Do you think there is another solution on this?

Comment: When the question is of the type "*I have this, I want that*", without specific logic, usually it's difficult to provide a better answer...